# How to set portable python path in portable Visual Studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, portability, pythonpath

I am trying to run python file in portable Visual Studio Code.
I added `"python.pythonPath":"./../"` in `launch.json` file to set path.

But it doesn't work.
I need to set python path in vscode. I want to execute on portable python interpreter. What can  I do for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you entered "../../", what did you think that was relative to?  `python.pythonPath` should have the absolute path to your Python interpreter.  It should start from `C:` and it should end with `python.exe`.  The `Python: Select Interpreter` command (from Ctrl-Shift-P) can help you choose this.